# How does the SiftDescriptorExtractor from OpenCV convert descriptor values?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, feature-descriptor

I have a question about the last part of the SiftDescriptorExtractor job,

I'm doing the following:

```
    SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat descriptors_object;
    extractor.compute( img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
```

Now I want to check the elements of a descriptors_object Mat object:

```
std::cout<< descriptors_object.row(1) << std::endl;
```

output looks like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 33, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 114, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 51, 154, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 154, 154, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 154, 148, 18, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 154, 61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 60, 154, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34, 70, 6, 15, 3, 2, 1, 0, 14, 16, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 154, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 154, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

But in [Lowe paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) it is stated that:

> Therefore, we reduce the influence of
>   large gradient magnitudes by
>   thresholding the values in the unit
>   feature vector to each be no larger
>   than 0.2, and then renormalizing to
>   unit length. This means that matching
>   the magnitudes for large gradients is
>   no longer as important, and that the
>   distribution of orientations has
>   greater emphasis. The value of 0.2 was
>   determined experimentally using images
>   containing differing illuminations for
>   the same 3D objects.

So the numbers from the feature vector should be no larger than 0.2 value.

The question is, how these values have been converted in a Mat object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So the numbers from the feature vector should be no larger than 0.2
>   value.

No. The paper says that SIFT descriptors are:

1. normalized (with L2 norm)
2. truncated using `0.2` as a threshold (i.e. loop over the normalized values and truncate when appropriate)
3. normalized again

So in theory any SIFT descriptor component is between `[0, 1]`, even though in practice the effective range observed is smaller (see below).

> The question is, how these values have been converted in a Mat object?

They are converted from floating-point values to `unsigned char`-s.

Here's the related section from OpenCV `modules/nonfree/src/sift.cpp` `calcSIFTDescriptor` method:

```
float nrm2 = 0;
len = d*d*n;
for( k = 0; k < len; k++ )
    nrm2 += dst[k]*dst[k];
float thr = std::sqrt(nrm2)*SIFT_DESCR_MAG_THR;
for( i = 0, nrm2 = 0; i < k; i++ )
{
    float val = std::min(dst[i], thr);
    dst[i] = val;
    nrm2 += val*val;
}
nrm2 = SIFT_INT_DESCR_FCTR/std::max(std::sqrt(nrm2), FLT_EPSILON);
for( k = 0; k < len; k++ )
{
    dst[k] = saturate_cast<uchar>(dst[k]*nrm2);
}
```

With:

```
static const float SIFT_INT_DESCR_FCTR = 512.f;
```

This is because classical SIFT implementations quantize the normalized floating point values into `unsigned char` integer through a 512 multiplying factor, which is equivalent to consider that any SIFT component varies between `[0, 1/2]`, and thus avoid to loose precision trying to encode the full `[0, 1]` range.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! So now we have float dst with 128 values for each keypoint. How to put them all in a Mat object?

Comment: If `N` keypoints have been detected, the descriptors are stored into a `N x 128` matrix, i.e. `N` rows where each row (= keypoint) has 128 columns to store the SIFT components.

Comment: in addition one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038797/how-to-use-sift-algorithm-with-a-color-inverted-image