# What is the right output type of SIFT descriptors on OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, types, sift, feature-descriptor

What is the right output type of SIFT descriptors on OpenCV?

I am asking this because I know that it is **float/double**, but when I try to save the descriptors on a file it saves some **int** values...

My code:

```
    cv::Mat img;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> imgKeypoints;
    cv::Mat imgDescriptors;
    cv::DescriptorExtractor *extractor;
    cv::FeatureDetector *detector;

    img = cv::imread(this->imageFileName.c_str(), cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    detector = new cv::DenseFeatureDetector(15.0, 1, 0.1, 6, 0, true, false);
    extractor = new cv::SIFT(0, 3, 0.04, 10.0, 1.6);

    extractor->compute(this->img, this->imgKeypoints, this->imgDescriptors);

    std::ofstream fout(outputFile.data());
    //I need to save it on this specified format
    for (int i = 0; i < this->imgDescriptors.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->imgDescriptors.cols; j++)
            fout << " " << float(this->imgDescriptors.at<float>(i,j));
    }
```

The output file comes like this:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 2 3 10 13 10 1 1 0 24 5 2 3 5 1 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 7 4 2 1 2 2 23 13 27 30 35 19 21 35 96 16 15 35 43 12 9 123 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 1 1 2 2 4 7 7 45 8 27 66 27 17 41 127 57 18 82 100 67 14 16 90 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 1 17 9 1 2 30 143 26 50 168 168 4 5 107 168 58 86 168 74 14 5 54

They are all **int** values, right? Is it right??? Shouldn't it be **float**?

Comment: Yes, it is right. It is float and then scaled by multiplying by 512 - that is why is is integer.

Comment: scaled by multiplying by 512? Why? Didn't get it...

Can I save them without this scaled/multiplied?

Comment: Wow! I got the answer from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911770/how-does-the-siftdescriptorextractor-from-opencv-convert-descriptor-values

Thanks anyway. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Wow! I got the answer from another question: [How does the SiftDescriptorExtractor from OpenCV convert descriptor values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911770/how-does-the-siftdescriptorextractor-from-opencv-convert-descriptor-values)

> This is because classical SIFT implementations quantize the normalized
>   floating point values into unsigned char integer through a 512
>   multiplying factor, which is equivalent to consider that any SIFT
>   component varies between [0, 1/2], and thus avoid to loose precision
>   trying to encode the full [0, 1] range.

Sorry for the duplication... =S