# OpenCV Help - Error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘cv::Mat’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, sift, operation

In OpenCV 2.4.10 I want to convert a row matrix to a matrix 12x12:

```
//Extraction SIFT
  SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
  Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
  extractor.compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
  extractor.compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

  Mat matrix(12,12, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0));
  int j = 0;
  for (int x = 0; x<12; x++)
  {
     for (int y = 0; y<12; y++)
     {
      matrix [x][y] = descriptors_2[x][j];
      j++

     }

  }
```

The error on line 67 `no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘cv::Mat’ and ‘int’)`.
Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `matrix.at<unsigned char>(y,x) = descriptors.at< unsigned char>(j,x)` note that it should be row-column order when accessing each element see http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat

Comment: Why don't you just [`reshape`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#abca74fa43163dba52b70af4b48c69f62) the Mat? (the same function is available in 2.4.x as well)

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe it will help;

```
Vec3f intensity = descriptors_2.at<Vec3f>(j, i);
matrix.at<unsigned char>(j,i)[0] = internsity.val[0];
matrix.at<unsigned char>(j,i)[1] = internsity.val[1];
matrix.at<unsigned char>(j,i)[2] = internsity.val[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

cv::Mat is not like std::vector or std::array. The internal data of cv::Mat is uchar*. You need to determine type of data you want to retrieve by at function http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at.

The returned descriptor is float, so your matrix type should be CV32FC1. [How does the SiftDescriptorExtractor from OpenCV convert descriptor values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911770/how-does-the-siftdescriptorextractor-from-opencv-convert-descriptor-values)